# expected string or bytes-like object when calling model subclass

Tags: conv-neural-network, typeerror, keras-layer

I have attempted to write a generative adversarial network. Below is the code of one of the discriminators.

```
class D1(Layer):
def __init__ (self, input_shape=(256, 256, 3), name='d1', **kwargs):
    super(D1, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.h1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')
    self.h2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='same')
    self.h3 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)
    self.h4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')
    self.h5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')
    self.h6 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='same')
    self.h7 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)
    self.h8 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')
    self.h9 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')
    self.h10 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='same')
    self.h11 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)
    self.h12 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')
    self.h13 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')
    self.h14 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='same')
    self.h15 = Flatten()
    self.h16 = Dropout(0.4)
    self.D1R = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    self.h17 = Dense(4096, activation='relu')
    self.h18 = Dense(4096, activation='relu')
    self.D1C = Dense(16, activation='sigmoid')

def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.h1(inputs)
    x = self.h2(x)
    x = self.h3(x)
    x = self.h4(x)
    x = self.h5(x)
    x = self.h6(x)
    x = self.h7(x)
    x = self.h8(x)
    x = self.h9(x)
    x = self.h10(x)
    x = self.h11(x)
    x = self.h12(x)
    x = self.h13(x)
    x = self.h14(x)
    x = self.h15(x)
    x = self.h16(x)
    d1r = self.D1R(x)
    x = self.h17(x)
    x = self.h18(x)
    d1c = self.D1C(x)
    

    return d1r, d1c'''

class Discriminator1(Model):
def __init__(
    self,
    input_shape=(None, 256, 256, 3),
    name='disc1',
    **kwargs
):  
    super(Discriminator1, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.d1 = D1(input_shape=input_shape)

def call(self, inputs):
    image = inputs
    d1r, d1c = self.d1(image)
    d1_loss = d1_loss(d1r, d1c)
    self.add_loss(d1_loss)
    return out
```

When I call it in training, it throws a TypeError: expected string or byte-like object. I cannot figure what it is.
Any help? None of my functions are supposed to use strings

```
  '''def generate_latent_noise(latent_dim, n_samples):
        x_input = randn(latent_dim * n_samples)
        x_input = x_input.reshape(n_samples, latent_dim)
        return x_input'''
  '''def generate_fake_samples(g, latent_dim, n_samples, y_i, y_l):
         x_input = generate_latent_noise(latent_dim, n_samples)
         X = g.predict(x_input)
         y = zeros((n_samples, 1))
         for i in range(n_samples-1):
           intent = y_i[i]
           bio = y_l[i]
        return X, y, intent, bio'''

  '''epochs = 200
     opt = SGD(learning_rate=1e-3, momentum=0.99)
     metric = Accuracy()
     yi, yl = retrieve_target_labels('/content/drive/My Drive/Project/input.xlsx')
     g = Generator(100)
     d1 = D1((256, 256, 3))
     d2 = D2((256, 256, 3))
     gen = G_Model((256, 256, 3), 100, yi, yl)
     disc1 = Discriminator1((256, 256, 3), 100)
     disc2 = Discriminator2((256, 256, 3), 100)
     art, yc_real, yi_real, yl_real =load_real_samples('/content/drive/MyDrive/Project/TrainSA.xlsx')
     half_batch = yi.shape[0]
     n_batch = half_batch * 2
     batch_per_epoch = int(art.shape[0]/n_batch)
     for epoch in range(epochs):
         for batch in range(batch_per_epoch):
             fake, y, yi, yl = generate_fake_samples(g, 100, half_batch, yi, yl)

             real, y_real, c_real, i_real, l_real = generate_real_samples(art, half_batch, yc_real, yi_real, yl_real)
    
            fake_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(fake)
    
            d1r, d1c = d1(fake_image) #error!
            d1_loss_fake = d1.losses
            d1r, d1c = d1(real)
            d1_loss = d1.losses
            d2i_fake, d2l_fake = d2(fake_image)
            d2_loss_fake = d2.losses
            d2i, d2l = d2(real)
            d2_loss = d2.losses
            g_loss = gen.losses '''
```

It is a bit difficult to provide a minimal working example as the error is at the end of my code, after a lot of functions have been called, but I tried to include the ones that might be involved in the error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-95-d4bb0da7c68f> in <module>()
      23         #d1_loss_fake = d1.losses
      24         real_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(real, dtype = tf.float32)
 ---> 25         d1r, d1c = disc1(real_image)
      26         d1_loss = d1.losses
      27         d2i_fake, d2l_fake = d2(fake_image)

 3 frames
 /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in 
name_scope(self, name)
   4126         # Scopes created in the root must match the more restrictive
   4127         # op name regex, which constrains the initial character.
-> 4128         if not _VALID_OP_NAME_REGEX.match(name):
   4129           raise ValueError("'%s' is not a valid scope name" % name)
   4130     old_stack = self._name_stack

  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Is this the best [mre] you can provide? What I mean is have you tried shortening your code to the point where you can get it with the smallest amount of code? Also Please include the full error log as that can sometimes give a lot of information.